# Clojure content-type?

Tags: clojure, content-type

I am writing a web service that uses JSON or optional **Clojure data** expressions as the body format. The data is just to be read, not evaluated, if that matters. What would you recommend to use as MIME or Content-type for Clojure?

This is how far I came:
Depending on how you look at it Clojure data might be Type "x", "text" or multipurpose "application":

```
application/clojure
text/clojure
application/x-clojure
```

At http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/ I could not even find a type for Lisp... (but then again Clojure is not Lisp).

There is of course the two versions

```
application/json
application/javascript
```

for JSON and JavaScript, depending on if the data will be evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standards are established as much by use as by design.  If the text you're sending is a clojure form, then I'm inclined to think `application/clojure` is fine.  The one reservation I have would be distinguishing executable code from literal data structures, much in the way `application/javascript` is distinguished from `application/json`.

Comment: Seems so. I was hoping that I had missed an already established standard for this. I have seen traces of these versions "in the wild", for exaple in pygments and in moinmoin.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something around:

- application/vnd.clojure-data
- application/prs.jramb.clojure-data
- text/vnd.clojure
- text/prs.jramb.clojure

see The part 3.2 and 3.3 from [rfc4288](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4288#section-3.2) and the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#List_of_common_media_types)

Comment: Yes, this maybe is correct if you see it from the point of view of a standard organization (IANA). However by using a private namespace (vnd or prs) I have excluded the possibility to follow any external standard. As I see it the personal and vendor namespaces would be usefull if I intended to establish a personal standard (which I do not intend). And since I am not the vendor of Clojure it would be wrong to use that as well. Also the RFC reserves vnd for commercially products which I think does not apply to clojure.

Comment: I can understand your point of view but i think it can be of your concern if the "application/clojure" would be registered by IANA. So I would use the prs just in case. So you will avoid conflict in name and maybe unintended consequences. But that I don't see a specific problem right now with the name clojure :) . Now with another language like 'Go' i would certainly have a problem with a application/go because we could imagine that this media-type would be officially used in by the Japanese or Chinese Go player association and that could be very unpleasant.